# Unable to Install Wkhtmltopdf on my Cpanel-Godaddy Shared Hosting

Tags: python, python-3.x, wkhtmltopdf

I have a shared hosting plan with GoDaddy without root access. I am trying to install [Wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/). I have tried the following steps but because I don't have the root access I a unalbe to complete the operation-

```
$ wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.4/wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz
tar -xvf wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz
```

But it is returning the following error-

```
tar (child): xz: Cannot exec: Permission denied
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I have read different answers with the same problem but the inly recommended solutions are-

1. Contact the root user to grant root access
2. Get a VPS

Is there any way to install the following software besides the above two solutions. If not, is there any library that provides the same functionality for python?

Any help would be appreciated.